# Reduce expanded image size in jqDock

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, user-interface, fisheye

I'm using [jqDock](http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/) on my web site. From what I understand the 'expanded' size of the image should be the maximum size of the image i.e. if it's a 64x64px image then when the mouse rolls over it, it should expand to 64px high.

It doesn't appear to work this way because no matter what size image I use, it always expands to 128x128px - too large for my liking.

Can anyone tell me how to have a smaller expanded image?

Edit: After further testing, it seems that it is just IE that does this. jqDock works as expected in Firefox and Safari. I need it to work in IE though so solutions are still required.

Comment: No, the page is on an intranet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't due to IE, rather the fact that the page is hosted within SharePoint.

Even though I had uploaded new versions of the images to the containing list, the SIZE of the images is somehow cached by SharePoint. Deleting the image and uploading a new copy does nothing. Renaming the same image and it works fine.

So to fix my problem, I simply added a 1 to the name of each image and the now size correctly.